# Creating and writing file in to /data folder of android device

Tags: android

Hi I need to create and write the text file in to /data directory..

this is the code I am using for this.

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("chmod 777 /data");
    process.waitFor();

    resultFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                            + "/resultfile.txt");
    Log.i(TAG,"File Object Created....."+resultFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Exception in Environment.getDataDirectory()"
               + e.toString());
}

try {
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("chmod 777 /data/resultfile.txt");
        process.waitFor();

        if (!resultFile.exists())
            resultFile.createNewFile();

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception in creating file..."
                   + ioException.toString());
    }

    try {
        if (fileWriter == null)
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(resultFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            Log.i(TAG, "FileNotFoundException....."
                       + fileNotFoundException.toString());
    }
```

but I am getting these below problems...

```
Exception in creating file...java.io.IOException: Permission denied

FileNotFoundException.....java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/resultfile.txt (Permission denied)

Exception  in saveResultsToFile.....java.lang.NullPointerException
```

plz help me in this...  thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This won't work because you don't have any permissions to write in there. That directory is owned by root.

Comment: Then what's the alternate for this I don't want to store in Shared preferences or external storage...

Comment: You don't have any other option. You can either save stuff in your applications private area or on the external storage.

Comment: what's meant by applications private area , can plz elaborate this..??

Comment: You should read the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) documentation page.